# PHP - preg_match/preg_replace problems

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm a little confused with preg_match and preg_replace. I have a very long content string (from a blog), and I want to find, separate and replace all [caption] tags. Possible tags can be:

```
[caption]test[/caption]
[caption align="center" caption="test" width="123"]<img src="...">[/caption]
[caption caption="test" align="center" width="123"]<img src="...">[/caption]
```

etc.

Here's the code I have (but I'm finding that's it not working the way I want it to...):

```
public function parse_captions($content) {
    if(preg_match("/\[caption(.*) align=\"(.*)\" width=\"(.*)\" caption=\"(.*)\"\](.*)\[\/caption\]/", $content, $c)) {
        $caption = $c[4];         
        $code = "<div>Test<p class='caption-text'>" . $caption . "</p></div>";
        // Here, I'd like to ONLY replace what was found above (since there can be
        // multiple instances
        $content = preg_replace("/\[caption(.*) width=\"(.*)\" caption=\"(.*)\"\](.*)\[\/caption\]/", $code, $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to ignore the content position. You can try this:

```
$subject = <<<'LOD'
[caption]test1[/caption]
[caption align="center" caption="test2" width="123"][/caption]
[caption caption="test3" align="center" width="123"][/caption]
LOD;

$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
\[caption                          # begining of the tag 
(?>[^]c]++|c(?!aption\b))*         # followed by anything but c and ]
                                   # or c not followed by "aption"

(?|                                # alternation group
    caption="([^"]++)"[^]]*+]      # the content is inside the begining tag  
  |                                # OR
    ]([^[]+)                       # outside 
)                                  # end of alternation group

\[/caption]                        # closing tag
~x
LOD;

$replacement = "<div>Test<p class='caption-text'>$1</p></div>";

echo htmlspecialchars(preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject));
```

pattern (condensed version):

```
$pattern = '~\[caption(?>[^]c]++|c(?!aption\b))*(?|caption="([^"]++)"[^]]*+]|]([^[]++))\[/caption]~';
```

pattern explanation:

After the *begining of the tag* you could have content before `]` or the caption attribute. This content is describe with:

```
(?>                # atomic group
    [^]c]++        # all characters that are not ] or c, 1 or more times
  |                # OR
    c(?!aption\b)  # c not followed by aption (to avoid the caption attribute)
)*                 # zero or more times
```

The alternation group `(?|` allow multiple capture groups with the same number:

```
(?|
       # case: the target is in the caption attribute #
    caption="      # (you can replace it by caption\s*+=\s*+")
    ([^"]++)       # all that is not a " one or more times (capture group)
    "
    [^]]*+         # all that is not a ] zero or more times

  |           # OR

       # case: the target is outside the opening tag #
    ]              # square bracket close the opening tag
    ([^[]+)        # all that is not a [ 1 or more times (capture group)
)
```

The two captures have now the same number #1

Note: if you are sure that each caption tags aren't on several lines, you can add the m modifier at the end of the pattern.

Note2: all quantifiers are [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) and i use [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) when it's possible for quick fails and better performances.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hint (and not an answer, per se)

Your best method of action would be:

1. Match everything after `caption`.

   ```
   preg_match("#\[caption(.*?)\]#", $q, $match)
   ```
2. Use an explode function for extracting values in `$match[1]`, if any.

   ```
   explode(' ', trim($match[1]))
   ```
3. Check the values in array returned, and use in your code accordingly.